# sharing global array amongst map-reduce tasks

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, global-variables

I need to keep a global array of strings across all map and reduce tasks, which each one of them can update while running.

Is is possible to do that in hadoop 1.2.1?

As far as I understood, counters only work with type long, and distributed cache files are read-only.

Would be great if someone can give pointers for this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: `Hadoop` is not supporting writable global shared resources. Running map and reduce tasks independently and in parallel is the main concept of it.

Comment: ok..thanks. Since counters were available, I thought it might be possible to have other shared variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should not have shared variables in map-reduce programs.

But if you really need it check the zookeeper, it is a distributed coordination service and is a core part of hadoop ecosystem. You can use it to store any kind of shared data, including arrays of strings.